# Python function comparing characters in two strings

Tags: python, function, compare

I would like to write my own Python function (i.e. without using any other non base Python functions) to compare the characters in two strings in the following way.

- If the letter in position `i` of *string 1* is the same as the letter in position `i` of *string 2* then `"Green"` is returned
- If the letter in position `i` of *string 1* is the same as the letter in position `[i-1]` or `[i+1]` of *string 2* then `"Blue"` is returned
- If the letter in position `i` of *string 1* is not the same as the letters in position `[i-1]` , `i` or `[i+1]` of *string 2* then `"White"` is returned

The final output of the function should be a tuple of the `"Green"` / `"Blue"` / `"White"` output for each letter.

For example, if we call the function `letter_comparison` and write:

```
def letter_comparison(string1, string2):
.....
```

`letter_comparison("chain", "chant")` would return `"Green"`, `"Green"`, `"Green"`, `"White"`, `"Blue"`.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What should be returned if the two strings don't have the same length? Can one letter be used for two evaluations e.g. what would be the expected result for `letter_comparison("hall", "paul")`?

Comment: @po.pe If the two strings don't have the same length then I would like an error message to be returned. The expected output for letter_comparison("hall", "paul") would be "White", "Green", "Blue", "Green"

Comment: According to your rules, a letter can satisfy both the requirements for "Blue" and the requirements for "White" since you could have equality in position `i-1` and difference in position `i+1`. In any event -- what have you tried? This question reads like an attempt to have Stack Overflow do homework for you.

Comment: Thanks - I should have been clearer "Blue" takes priority over "White"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `for` loop?

```py
def letter_comparison(string1, string2):
  myList = []

  if len(string1) != len(string2):
    return
  
  for i in range(len(string1)):
    try:
      l2p = string2[i+1]
    except:
      l2p = None
    try:
      l2m = string2[i-1]
    except:
      l2m = None

    if string1[i] == string2[i]:
      myList.append("Green")
    elif string1[i] == l2p or string1[i] == l2m:
      myList.append("Blue")
    else:
      myList.append("White")

  return myList

otherList = letter_comparison("chain", "chant")
print(otherList)
```

Otherwise, the question was pretty clear and you did a good job.

Comment: Thanks @DeitzNuts this is really helpful - I knew that a for loop would be helpful but I wasn't aware of the try statement. Apologies for the very basic question (I'm very new to Python) but your solution code only seems to return the final character comparison - how do I get the for loop to output a tuple for each position comparison i.e. in the case of "chain" and "chant" to output a tuple containing "Green", "Green", "Green", "White", "Blue"?

Comment: It's perfectly good, since we all start somewhere. Also, I did not see the part where you wanted it in a tuple, so I'm sorry. Tuples are immutable, meaning they can't change, so you would most likely have to use a list. I have edited the code for a list, since lists are mutable.

Comment: Thanks! Having the output as a list rather than tuple is fine, however using that code I get a list with only the final outcome again rather than a list of all of the appended outcomes from the loop, and I'm not sure why?

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I am using Python version 3

Comment: To find out, write `python -V` in the shell of the IDE you are using.

Comment: Version 3.9.13.

Comment: I am using 3.8.12, so this could be a reason

Answer (score 0):

In this way, the function still works depending on the length of the words.
I have divided it into two functions for convenience.

```
def Test(word1,word2,pos):
    if word1[pos] == word2[pos]:
        return "Green"
    elif (pos < (len(word1)-2)) and (word1[pos] == word2[pos+1]):
        return "Blue"
    elif (pos>0) and (word1[pos] == word2[pos-1]):
        return "Blue"
    else:
        return "White"

def letter_comparison(test1, test2):
    risultato = []
    if len(test1) < len(test2):
        for count, char in enumerate(test1):
            risultato.append(Test(test1, test2, count))
    else:
        for count, char in enumerate(test2):
            risultato.append(Test(test1, test2, count))
    return risultato
```